# American Zebra optimization adaptation problem in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, optimization, dataset

```
def fobj(solution):
    selected_features = [i for i, selected in enumerate(solution) if selected]
    
    X_subset = X[:, selected_features]  # Select the corresponding columns from the dataset

    # Split the data into training and testing sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_subset, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

    # Create a Random Forest classifier
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier()

    # Train the classifier
    rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Predict the labels for the test set
    y_pred = rfc.predict(X_test)

    # Calculate the accuracy score as the fitness value
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    return accuracy


epoch = 100
pop_size = 50



# Step 2: Define the optimization problem as a dictionary
problem = {
    "fit_func": fobj,
    "lb": [0] * num_features,
    "ub": [.6] * num_features,
    "minmax": "max",
    
    
}

# Step 1: Create an instance of the AZOA class
model = AZOA(N, Max_iter, lb, ub, dim, fobj)

# Step 4: Call the solve method and get the result
best_position, best_fitness = model.solve(problem)

# Step 5: Print or use the best position and fitness
print(f"Best Solution: {best_position}")
print(f"Best Fitness: {best_fitness}")
```

I am trying to implement for a feature selection problem for a dataset. But it gives me following error
"Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(292, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required."

Comment: If none of the `solution` are selected, then `X_subset` has 0 features. What is `AZOA`? Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).